# Regular expression to parse FTP link string

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following code to parse the parts of an FTP link:

```
Regex exp = new Regex(@"(?i)ftp:\/\/(?<user>\S+?):(?<passwd>\S+?)@(?<host>\S+?.\S+?.\S+?.\S+?)");
Match m = exp.Match(@"Link: ftp://username:password@host.sub.domain.tld<ftp://username:password@host.sub.domain.tld/>");

Console.WriteLine("Host = " + m.Groups["host"].Value);
Console.WriteLine("User = " + m.Groups["user"].Value);
Console.WriteLine("Pass = " + m.Groups["passwd"].Value);
```

Which produces the following output:

```
Host = host.su
User = username
Pass = password
```

Why is the host being truncated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `\S` will match also the dot character and `.` would match any character.

```
@"(?i)ftp:\/\/(?<user>\S+?):(?<passwd>\S+?)@(?<host>[^.\s]+\.[^.\s]+\.[^.\s]+\.\w+)"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bO6dY5/2)

**Why?**

```
(?<host>\S+?.\S+?.\S+?.\S+?)
```

- `\S+?` - Matches the first charcter because of non-greediness.
- `.` - Matches the second character, since an unescaped dot would match any character.
- Likewise it matches only first 7 chars in the host part.

Comment: Welp, now you've edited in a comment on non-greediness my answer just looks like it was too late.

Answer (score 6):

Parsing Uri's is already done in .NET. The syntax of URIs has too many edge cases and variations to just use a regex.

So use the inbuilt support:

```
var u = new Uri("ftp://username:password@host.sub.domain.tld");

var host = u.Host;
var ui = u.UserInfo.Split(':')
var user = ui[0];
var pwd = ui[1];
```

Comment: I don't have a clean string with the URI - I'm trying to find it in a block of text, hence the regular expression.